# Forward declaring a template's member typedef

Tags: c++, c++11

I use a library (which I cannot modify) and that declares a **PointCloud** template that includes a **Ptr** **typedef**

```
namespace pcl
{
    template <typename PointT>
    class PCL_EXPORTS PointCloud
    {
        ...
        typedef boost::shared_ptr<PointCloud<PointT> > Ptr;
    }
}
```

Now, I need to forward declare **Ptr** and I have no idea how to. I have done

```
namespace pcl
{
    class PointXYZ;
    template<class pointT> class PointCloud;
}
```

but I am stuck here and whatever I do, I do not seem to be able to forward declare the **Ptr** **typedef**.

Any idea?

**----------EDIT----------**

The reason why I need this forward declaration is that I need to declare a function into a header of my own. And I am expecting this function to take a **PointCloud< PointXYZ >::Ptr** as argument, because the **PointCloud** I want to feed into the function is stored into a **PointCloud< PointXYZ >::Ptr**.

Comment: You cannot do this.

Comment: What's the actual problem that you're trying to solve? Hacking around with your own declarations of a library's classes and their members is almost always not the right answer.

Comment: I dont understand why you think you need to predeclare a typedef. Maybe it is my confusion, but if you know how to declare it, you dont need the typedef in the first place, no?

Comment: I have added an edit which should give more details.

Comment: Then just use `boost::shared_ptr<PointCloud<PointXYZ> >` in your function? Or you can make the function a template, and make it use `boost::shared_ptr<PointCloud<T> >` for any kind of `T`.

Comment: Well, you can probably use alias instead... but you cannot use existing typedef so if the library changes, you have to update your declarations...

Comment: The usual way to do that is for your header to `#include` the header that has the definitions of `PointCloud`, then just declare the function to take `PointCloud<PointXYZ>::Ptr`.

Comment: Five bucks says this whole thing ends with an explanation of `typename` for dependent types.

Comment: @Sneftel: I am not sure I understand your statement...

Comment: You can just forward declare the type, and if you want, make YOUR OWN typedef, `using LibFooPtr = boost::shared_ptr<LibFooType>;` ? Your type def does not need to be identical to the library type def.

Comment: I got a few different relevant answers here, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Typedefs are aliases for types.  They are not types themselves, if that makes sense.

```
namespace pcl
{
  class PointXYZ;
  template<class pointT> class PointCloud;
}
template<class T>
using foo = boost::shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<T>>;
```

`foo<X>` is the same type as `pcl::PointCloud<T>::Ptr`.